# How do I write an ElasticSearch query to find unique elements in columns?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

For example, if I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct emp_id, salary FROM TABLE_EMPLOYEE
```

what would be its ElasticSearch equivalent?

This is what I have come up with until now:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Employee": {
      "terms": {
        "field":["emp_id", "salary" ]
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is everything indexed? If you are saying you want the distinct `emp_id` and `salary` then why not just query directly? It shouldn't be denormalized far as I know.

Comment: How would I query them directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending a list of fields to perform **distinct** upon, send them as separate aggregations.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "Employee": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "emp_id",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "Salary":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "salary",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer from our conversation you would issue the following http command using curl.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/<your index>/<type>/_search?pretty
```